# hashlib.sha3_256 Python in C#

Tags: python, c#, sha256, hashlib

I'm trying to hash a string/token, and I'm not getting the same hash result in C# that I get in Python.

String to hash:
`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IkdVU1RBVk8uQlJFU09MSU5AQklHREFUQUNPUlAuQ09NLkJSIiwibmJmIjoxNjc4Mjk5NTA2LCJleHAiOjE2NzgzMDMxMDYsImlhdCI6MTY3ODI5OTUwNiwiaXNzIjoiQmlnIERhdGEgQ29ycC4iLCJwcm9kdWN0cyI6W10sImRvbWFpbiI6IkFETUlOIn0.AZufGQwwpilAjyVe9Rzc8ByI-xFYX6wf8SJUbiPMROQ`

Result in Python with hashlib.sha3_256 and hexdigest :
`501e1a7e062c8b53be510fb361fd937d55f98c480de90bfb4be2e71fd2d0a46a`

Result in C# with SHA256Managed:
`326fa626da197be117a5130aa19e75899e7dbcdd5fe730177a43da04b0568482`

Method in C# .netCore:

```
public static string ComputeSha256Hash(string rawData)
{
    var crypt = new SHA256Managed();
    string hash = String.Empty;
    byte[] crypto = crypt.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));
    foreach (byte theByte in crypto)
    {
        hash += theByte.ToString("x2");
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Method in Python:

```
generate_token():
requested_products = g.request_data.products

issued_at = datetime.utcnow()
expiration_dt = issued_at + timedelta(hours=g.request_data.expires)

# building jwt token payload
payload = {
    'unique_name': g.request_data.login,
    'nbf': issued_at,
    'exp': expiration_dt,
    'iat': issued_at,
    'iss': constants.ISSUER,
    'products': list(requested_products),
    'domain': g.user_info["Group"]
}

# generating token
token = jwt.encode(payload, COMMUNICATION_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
# encrypting token to guarantee secure storage
hash_token = hashlib.sha3_256(token)
# storing encrypted token in database & returning it's id
token_id = jwtdb.jwtconf_save(
    hash_token.hexdigest(),
    issued_at,
    g.user_info["Group"],
    g.request_data.login,
    expiration_dt,
    list(requested_products))
```

I've tried changing the encoding to Encoding.ASCII without success.

Comment: *I'm not getting the same hash result* - I inserted the word *not*, guess that's what you wanted to say. Could you pls. also show the Python code?